# Multivariable function continous, differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi im wondering if the following is correct?

Let g be a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by

\begin{equation}
    g(x,y)=
    \begin{cases}
      \sin(2x+3y)+{xy^2\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & \text{if $(x,y)\neq 0$}\\
      0 & \text{if $(x,y)=0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

a) Show that g is continous on $\mathbb{R}^{2}.$

b) Compute the first order partial derivatives of g at $(0,0).$

c) Show that g is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and give its differential at this point.

d)  Show that g is of class ${C}^{1}$ on ${R}^{2}$.

a. It's continous if $$\mid{\sin(2x+3y)+{xy^2\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\mid=0.$$
as $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$

$\sin(2x+3y)$ obviously tends to 0 and $$\mid{xy^2\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\mid\leq{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}y^2\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=y^2=0$$

So g is continous.

b. $${\partial g\over \partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0} {g(h,0)-g(0,0)\over h}={\sin(2h)+{h\cdot0\over {h^2}}\over h}={\sin(2h)\over h}=2.$$
For ${\partial g\over \partial y}$ we do it in a similar way and get $${\partial g\over \partial y}(0,0)=3.$$

c. It's differentiable if $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-{\partial g\over \partial x}(0,0)h-{\partial g\over \partial y}(0,0)k\over {\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}}=0$$

We have $$ {\sin(2h+3k)+{hk^2\over \sqrt{h^2+k^2}}-0-2h-3k\over{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}}$$

But $\sin(2h+3k)$ tends towards $2h+3k$ so it cancels out and we get $${{hk^2\over \sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\over{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}}=\lim_{r\to 0} {r^3\cos({s})\sin^2({t})\over r^2}=r\cos({s})\sin^2({t})=0.$$
So it's differentiable.

d. It's ${C}^{1}$ if $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {\partial g\over \partial x}(x,y)={\partial g\over \partial x}(0,0)$$ and $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {\partial g\over \partial y}(x,y)={\partial g\over \partial y}(0,0)$$
which by calculation we see that they are.

Comment: You're correct. But $\frac{\frac{hk^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$ you only considered the radial limit.  You can calculate it like$|\frac{hk^2}{h^2+k^2}|\leq h$.

Comment: So it's not enough to just take the radial limit?

Comment: Yes. For example, $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}$ radial limit is $0$, but let $y=x^2-x$, then the limit equals to $\frac{1}{3}$.